# Programmatically add a strong named assembly to the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, gac

Is there anyway to programmatically add a strong named assembly to the GAC using C# code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Microsoft Support article, [*How to install an assembly into the Global Assembly Cache in Visual C#*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815808), should explain all you need to know.

This is typically a task performed by the installer, so I'm not sure why you'd want to do it from within a .NET program (unless I've misunderstood your question). However, you can simply use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to run all the necessary programs as an installer might.

Comment: Ok I will use the gacutil utility to add the assemblies to the Gac .. I thought there might be able to use an API to add an assembly to the GAC .. 
Thanks

Comment: No problem. And yeah, I very much doubt there's a library/API to do this for you. The task is simple enough to use the command-line tools however.

Comment: To clarify, will an installer (produced by VS) automatically install my srongly named assemblies to the GAC?

Answer (score 2):

The Global Assembly Cache is configured through a COM-like interface(http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317540).

For all questions about the GAC, Jungfen Zhang's blog is the source of choice.
http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/articles/229648.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/articles/229649.aspx

For more information, search for "managed GAC API".

> Gacutil.exe is only for development
>   purposes and should not be used to
>   install production assemblies into the
>   global assembly cache.
>
> [Microsoft Installer] is the recommended
>   and most common way to add assemblies
>   to the global assembly cache. The
>   installer provides reference counting
>   of assemblies in the global assembly
>   cache, plus other benefits.

Answer (score 1):

just call [gacutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(VS.80).aspx) command

```
gacutil /i mydll.dll
```

Comment: gacutil is a SDK command that may not be expected to be available on a user's machine

Comment: I can probably pack it as a resource .. extract it and run it .. correct ?

Comment: Yea, you can bundle GACUTIL.EXE with your installation package

Comment: I would not ship a version of gacutil that may or may not fit to the framework on the target machine.